# Android Calendar View Setting Date

Tags: java, android, calendar

Good evening all,

I am currently working with CalendarView in my Android App and what I am trying to do is basically put my own date as the current date into the calendar if that makes sense?

In a nutshell I want the calendar to show say the 21st August 2015 as the current date and access this and change as required.

Is this possible? I have tried things like this :-

```
package com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CalendarView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class Calendarschedule extends Activity
{
CalendarView calender;
Calendar calobj;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
    calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
    InitializeCalendar();
}

public void InitializeCalendar()
{
    calender = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.schedulecal);
    calobj.setTimeInMillis(99999999);
    calobj.set(2015,8,21);
    calender.setShowWeekNumber(false);
    calender.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);



}
```

But it doesn't seem to work? Anyone done this before?

Cheers M.

Comment: calendar.setDate(calobj.getTimeInMillis()) not working?

Comment: public void InitializeCalendar()
    {
        calender = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.schedulecal);
        calobj.set(2014,8,21);
        calender.setDate(calobj.getTimeInMillis());
        calender.setShowWeekNumber(false);
        calender.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);



    }

Comment: Ive done this so far and this returns the 21st sept 2014 is that right? Only 8 month is that not august or is jan 0? Also how would you add plus one day to that? as in day++ sort of thing? Thank you for looking

Comment: yep 0 is Jan, please could you help with adding on the day++?

Comment: Months count from 0 alright.

Comment: Have a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int, int)